# Why KeyError 3 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Hi I don't know why I keep getting this key error and the data frame looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpXQS.png)

I want to find the first user who signed-up from California, from Oregon, etc. So here is my code

```
def find_first_user(df):
""" function to find the first user """
    idx = df['user_sign_up_date'].argmin()
    return df.loc[idx, ['user_id', 'user_sign_up_date']]

df.groupby('user_state').apply(find_first_user).sort_values(by='user_sign_up_date')
```

I cannot figure out where it's wrong( I have change my date time all to datetime type). Anyone has other ways to do this problem or suggestions?

Comment: The code in the function has no indent?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

1. As I mentioned in the comments your code is not indented.
2. You are using the loc function wrong:

> Allowed inputs are:
> A single label, e.g. 5 or 'a', (note that 5 is interpreted as a label of the index,  and never as an integer position along the index).
> A list or array of labels, e.g. ['a', 'b', 'c'].
> A slice object with labels, e.g. 'a':'f'.
> A boolean array of the same length as the axis being sliced, e.g. [True, False, True].
> An alignable boolean Series. The index of the key will be aligned before masking.
> An alignable Index. The Index of the returned selection will be the input.
> A callable function with one argument (the calling Series or DataFrame) and that >returns valid output for indexing (one of the above)
> See more at Selection by Label.

> Raises KeyError
> If any items are not found.

**This** is very likely your KeyError

From (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc)[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc]

And thanks I could help.